# scrolling vertically

Tags: iphone

i am using the following code to scroll image on scrooll view,

```
StoryViewScroller = [[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 79.0f, 320.0f, 262)] autorelease];
StoryViewScroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(NPAGES * 320.0f, StoryViewScroller.frame.size.height);
StoryViewScroller.pagingEnabled = YES;
StoryViewScroller.delegate = self;
StoryViewScroller.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
StoryViewScroller.scrollsToTop = YES;
// Load in all the pages
for (i = 0; i < NPAGES; i++)
{
    NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg", i+1];
    UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:filename]];
    iv.frame = CGRectMake(i * 320.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 262);
    [StoryViewScroller addSubview:iv];
    NSLog(@"I is :: %d" ,i);
    [iv release];
}

[self.view addSubview:StoryViewScroller];
```

this enable mein tos scroll view from left to right and vice versa.what should i change to sroll view to top to bottom and vice versa.

sugggestions

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable vertical scrolling set appropriate height to the contentSize, e.g.

```
StoryViewScroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0f, NPAGES*StoryViewScroller.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: sure - you need to set correct frame to your image views - change y origin coordinate instead of x in a loop. something like: iv.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, i*262.0f, 320.0f, 262);

Comment: yea..how stupid i m.....thanks Vladimir.  can i show 2 images at a time???. like its 1 image at a time is coming up, wat if, want to show 2 or three images on a view